# Разделить строку на кириллице на слова, используя String.split(regex)

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

В сервлет поступает строка из http-запроса (у запроса установлена кодировка utf-8). Разделяю строку на слова с помощью `split("\\W+")`. С латиницей работает, а с кириллицей - нет. Как разбить на не словесные символы строку на кириллице?

Comment: А если так: `split("[^а-яА-ЯёЁ\w]")`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за вариант, но ide почему-то ругается: `illegal character escape`

Comment: Забыл про экранирование: `split("[^а-яА-ЯёЁ\\w]")`

Comment: @gil9red от души благодарю. Работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split("\\W+")` выделяет слова только из ASCII символов.

`split("\\P{L}+")` выделяет слова на всех языках мира:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetWords {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            String[] words = line.split("\\P{L}+");
            for (String w : words) {
                System.out.println("\"" + w + "\"");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac GetWords.java
> $ echo "Hello world! Привет, мир! 你好，世界！" | java GetWords
> "Hello"
> "world"
> "Привет"
> "мир"
> "你好"
> "世界"
> ```

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение полностью решило мою проблему

Comment: Хорошее решение :)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте перечислить кириллицу в регулярке:

```
split("[^а-яА-ЯёЁ\\w]")
```

Comment: Ранее я принял ваш ответ, но позже заметил, что предложенная вами регулярка не справляется полностью, но всё же она была лучше того, что использовал я, спасибо вам. Регулярка предложенная @Stanislav Volodarskiy `split("\\P{L}+")` справляется с моей проблемой полностью, поэтому я принял его ответ.

Comment: @nikoshi, понятно, спасибо за пояснение :)